# replacing backtick with $() not working

Tags: bash

I have some old scripts that I try to update. Some of the code condenses to:

```
 export X=`(echo "abc"; echo "def")`
 echo $X
```

which gives the expected output:

```
 abc def
```

Now the internet tells me backticks are out `$()` is what I need to use, but when I try:

```
export X=$((echo "abc"; echo "def"))
```

`X` is not set and I get the error:

```
bash: echo "abc"; echo "def": syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ""abc"; echo "def"")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `$(( … ))` syntax is an [arithmetic expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04).

What is missing is a space between the `$(` and the following `(`, to avoid the arithmetic expression syntax.

The section on [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) in the shell command language specification actually warns for that:

```
If the command substitution consists of a single subshell, such as:

   $( (command) )

a conforming application shall separate the "`$(`" and '`(`' into two tokens
(that is, separate them with white space). This is required to avoid any
ambiguities with arithmetic expansion.
```

Comment: It should be noted that `\`...\`` and `$(...)` start a subshell anyway, so the inner `(...)` are not needed (waste a process). You'd need the space in things like `$( (...); (...) )` for instance (where the inner subshells may be needed).

Answer (score 15):

Try
`export X="$(echo "abc"; echo "def")"`

Comment: Thanks this does work, but requires more editing than the other solution.

Comment: +1 for including the quotes that are  needed in most POSIX shells (`ksh` and `bash` being the only exceptions).